# Deserialize binary file to array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization

I have serialized an array of objects. I want to deserialize them back into an array. The examples I have found either deserialize a single object or use a hashtable and cast that as a dictionary. Some other examples used an object graph, but I should be able to just cast it back into the source object. Here is my code...

```
        if(File.Exists(binData))
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(binData, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            ViewerData vd = new ViewerData();

            try
            {
                vd = (ViewerData)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
```

Can I enumerate the deserializesd data? Or can I deserialize it to an array?

Edit:

I am not getting any errors but that code does not return an array. The object contains 4 properties, 3 strings and an image. I need to be able to iterate through the result for it to be useful. I am serializing the object with the following...

```
        stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

        fileInfoArray = fileInfoList.ToArray();
        viewerData = new ViewerData[fileInfoArray.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < fileInfoArray.Length; i++)
        {
            viewerData[i] = new ViewerData(fileInfoArray[i]);
            bin.Serialize(stream, viewerData[i]);
        }
        stream.Close();
```

Everything works fine. How do I Deserialize the binary file back into an array of objects instead of one ViewerData object?

Comment: Please provide more details. Is there any error in your code or you are just asking if it works?

Comment: What are you serializing in the first place?

Comment: (too late to edit) I mean, what and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't serialize every object in the array. Serialize the whole array.
Also deserialize as an array.

Comment: I don't think this answer should have been picked as the 'solution', the best solution provides code examples rather than vague instructions

Comment: @DannyWatson The question contains the code sample, + the OP already knew how to do that. Perhaps I should've included samples, but the answer is just as brief as the question. ("How do I serialize an array of objects?" -> "Just serialize the array.")

Answer (score 4):

You are serialiazing each object separately but deserializing only one object. You can simply serialize whole array of objects:

```
// Serialize
bin.Serialize(stream, viewerData);

// Deserialize
var result = (ViewerData[])bin.Deserialize(fs);
```

Or serialize number of items and deserialize them in loop (knowing number of items):

```
// Serialize
bin.Serialize(stream, fileInfoArray.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < fileInfoArray.Length; i++)
{
    viewerData[i] = new ViewerData(fileInfoArray[i]);
    bin.Serialize(stream, viewerData[i]);
}

// Deserialize
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

int length = (int)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
{
    viewerData[i] = (ViewerData)bin.Deserialize(fs);        
}
```